# PHP Undefined constant error makes no sense

Tags: php, class, constants, undefined

I truly hope I've missed something simple here, but I'm running into a strange issue using class constants in PHP.  I created a simple class called Utils and added two class constants, CRYPT_SALT and LOGIN_PAGE.  I referenced those from other files, and they worked.  Then I added five more class constants, and they don't work.  I get "Fatal error: Undefined class constant '' in /var/www/modx/test.php on line ", where  is one of the new constants, and  is the line where I try to use it.

Here is the Utils class:

```
<?php
// 
// Utils.php
//  
// This class is a collection of static utility functions.  Since the methods are static, they should
// all be invoked with:
//
//  Utils::methodName();
//
// This class also contains global constants, which are *not* kept in Config.  They should be accessed with:
//
//  Utils::CONSTANT;
// 
// addToCSVString -- adds an incoming string to a CSV string, possibly prepending a comma and space.  Returns
// addToJSONString -- adds an incoming key/value pair to a JSON string
// jsonify -- takes in a string and replaces control characters and quotes with properly
//

require_once( "logger.php" );

class Utils {

        // Constants 

    const CRYPT_SALT    = '$6$';
    const LOGIN_PAGE    = '/modx/';

        // Session keys

    const SKEY_DEBUG    = 'debug';
    const SKEY_LOGIN    = 'login';
    const SKEY_LANG     = 'curLang';
    const SKEY_UID      = 'userID';
    const SKEY_LOGGER   = 'logger';


        // Members

    public static $debug    = false;

        // Methods

    //
    // addToCSVString -- adds an incoming string to a CSV string, possibly prepending a comma and space.  Returns
    // the new string
    //
    public static function addToCSVString( $csvString, $newVal ) {
        if ( strlen( $csvString ) > 0 ) {
            $csvString  .= ", ";
        }

        return $csvString . $newVal;
    }


    //
    // addToJSONString -- adds an incoming key/value pair to a JSON string
    //
    public static function addToJSONString( $jsonString, $key, $val ) {
        $debug      = self::$debug;

        if ( $debug ) {
            $logger = Logger::singleton();
            $logger->log( "In Utils::addToJSONString" );
            $logger->log( "\$key = [$key]", 1 );
            $logger->log( "\$val = [$val]", 1 );
        }

        if ( strpos( $val, "{" ) === false ) {

            if ( $debug ) {
                $logger->log( "Utils: this is a plain value", 1 );
            }
                // Val is a string

            $val    = self::jsonify( $val );

            return self::addToCSVString( $jsonString, "\"" . $key . "\" : \"" . $val . "\"" );
        } else {
            if ( $debug ) {
                $logger->log( "this is a JSON object", 1 );
            }

                // Val is a JSON object

            return self::addToCSVString( $jsonString, "\"" . $key . "\" : " . $val . "" );
        }
    }


    //
    // jsonify -- takes in a string and replaces control characters and quotes with properly
    // escaped JSON values
    //
    public static function jsonify( $val ) {
        $val    = str_replace( '\\', '\\\\', $val );        // convert backslashes first 
        $val    = str_replace( "\n", '\\n', $val );
        $val    = str_replace( "\r", '\\r', $val );
        $val    = str_replace( "\t", '\\t', $val );
        $val    = str_replace( "\v", '\\v', $val );
        $val    = str_replace( "\f", '\\f', $val );
        $val    = str_replace( "\n", '\\n', $val );
        $val    = str_replace( "\n", '\\n', $val );

        return $val;
    }


}

?>
```

All the member functions were written and tested before I added the class constants, they are working.

And here is test.php, a simple test page to illustrate the problem:

```
<h1>Test.php</h1>

<?php

    // Set up autoloader

spl_autoload_extensions( '.php,.inc' );
spl_autoload_register();

    // Test class constants

echo "<b>Testing Utils class constants</b></br>\n"; 
echo 'Utils::CRYPT_SALT = [' . Utils::CRYPT_SALT . "]<br>\n";
echo 'Utils::LOGIN_PAGE = [' . Utils::LOGIN_PAGE . "]<br>\n";
echo 'Utils::SKEY_LOGGER = [' . Utils::SKEY_LOGGER . "]<br>\n";
echo 'Utils::SKEY_DEBUG = [' . Utils::SKEY_DEBUG . "]<br>\n";
echo 'Utils::SKEY_LOGIN = [' . Utils::SKEY_LOGIN . "]<br>\n";
echo 'Utils::SKEY_LANG = [' . Utils::SKEY_LANG . "]<br>\n";
echo 'Utils::SKEY_UID = [' . Utils::SKEY_UID . "]<br>\n";
echo "</br>\n";

?>
```

The exact error I get from test.php is:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'SKEY_LOGGER' in /var/www/modx/test.php on line 15
```

I've tried the following to solve this:

-- Renaming the constants, including using lower case names without underscores

-- Changing the order of the declarations.

-- Changing from double to single quotes.

-- Commenting out the declarations for CRYPT_SALT and LOGIN_PAGE

-- Showing this code to my co-workers, who are all clueless

Regardless of anything I try, CRYPT_SALT and LOGIN_PAGE work, none of the other constants work.  I'm afraid I'm up against some bug deep in PHP's class system.  Or maybe I've just stared at this so long that I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: I put this all in a single file and do not encounter any errors -- it works perfectly. Try it on a different server, see what you get. The only part of your use case I could not reproduce is the file `logger.php`

Comment: I hate to ask, but are you sure the test.php file is actually including the same utils.php file you are working on and not the original copy with two constants? God knows I've banged my head against the wall doing stuff that silly before... The code you have should work.

Comment: What if you put the `echo Utils::SKEY_LOGGER;` right below the definition of that class?

Comment: I quite literally copy and pasted your code, removed the logger include and references (because I had no such class) and it worked just fine, outputting all constants as expected? What version of PHP are you using, and also; make sure you are including the right Utils.php file and are modifying the correct version. I've spent hours debugging only to find that I was changing the wrong file.

Comment: It [works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aTMJ9Q) and the one idea I had doesn't break it. I suggest you add an `echo` to the file with the class definition in to verify that you are definitely including the correct file.

Comment: @mrex: Start with accepting the fact that the PHP error message does not lie to you. Just accept it. Then start to think why that happens, verify your thoughts by facts. Stop guessing. Switch your brain more than just on. It need to run on it's highest power when debugging. Stop guessing. Start thinking.

Comment: I tested this as well, and it works fine. How are you including the file? What's in `logger.php`? These are important questions that need answering. What happens if you comment out `logger.php`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys!  I just thought of trying this on another server, I will do that tomorrow.  Your replies seem to have confirmed it, it must be something with this machine.  I will try the code on a dev server here in my office.  Also, I'll post the code for logger.php, its a singleton class the writes to a log file.

Finally, @hakre, I know it is me, and my misunderstanding of something.  I've been writing software since the 70's.  I always try to keep an open mind, it is the only way I get my code to work.

I'll post again tomorrow.

Comment: Perhaps you are using an old version of PHP on that server?

Comment: @mrex: Some tools for debugging: 1.) run a step debugger. That's normally the best to find out what is going on, but it's not always possible. So 2.) `debug_print_backtrace`; `get_included_files`; `var_dump`; `die`; ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

The answer is I am an idiot, as usual.  :)

I had a second copy of utils.php, in the main directory of the web.  That earlier version (with only CRYPT_SALT and LOGIN_PAGE defined) was the one the autoloader was finding first.

@Paolo Bergantino and @David, you were quite right to suggest making sure I was including the file I thought I was.  @hakre, thanks for the get_included_files tip.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in my system.

if you remove `"require_once( "logger.php" );"` into `Utils.php`, its working fine.

so, i thing problem in your `lonnger.php` file.

try it.